# Name for operation chunking a list of items into a list of pairs, where the 2nd item of each pair forms the first item of the next?

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, nested-lists

Is there a name for an operation that converts a list like:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

into:

```
[[A, B], [B, C], [C, D], [D, E], [E, F]]
```

and what is it? Relatedly, is there a name for that second data structure?

Comment: Sliding window with Length 2?

Comment: Kind of, but there isn't any other goal here besides transforming the data. Is that a requirement for sliding window algorithms? Is there such a thing as "sliding window chunking?" Seems like that mostly describes it if all else fails, but I was hoping for an official term.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with bigrams? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram